# Kubernetes: can't delete namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I just created a namespace, have done nothing with it and now deleted it. However, when I list contexts I can still see it there. It seems to have been deleted as I can't delete it again. Why can I still see it listed when I get contexts?

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         dev        minikube   minikube   dev
          minikube   minikube   minikube

kubectl delete namespace dev
namespace "dev" deleted

kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
*         dev        minikube   minikube   dev
          minikube   minikube   minikube
```

I switched contexts just in case but still get the same problem. E.g.

```
kubectl delete namespace dev
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "dev" not found

kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME       CLUSTER    AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
          dev        minikube   minikube   dev
*         minikube   minikube   minikube
```

Interestingly, I don't see it when I list namespaces. E.g.

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

Answer (score 5):

A `context` in `kubectl`is just a local config that contains details (metadata) about a particular cluster or a namespace. This is the config that is needed for cluster/namespace management using the `kubectl` client.

So, when you type `kubectl config <any_command>`, it's just doing a lookup in a file stored locally on you computer.
Run the following to know more about this command and how to control the location of the config file:

```
kubectl config --help
```

Deleting a cluster or a namespace does not delete the associated context. The reason is that the deleting of a cluster or a namespace is an asynchronous operation that runs on the cluster. This operation may take longer than a few seconds to actually finish. Thus, `kubectl` cannot immediately delete the context from the config file after you issues the delete to the cluster master.

To answer your question, you have to manually delete the context using:

```
kubectl config delete-context dev
```